# Google Map zoom not working

Tags: sxa

SXA Version: 1.8
Component: Maps

I am using SXA map component on my page and is connecting to Google Map. I have provided the coordinates.

I want to display the map zoomed to the street level. But irrespective of the value selected from drop-down for zoom, the map on my page is not that detailed.
Though the value selected a zoom level gets updated in the source.
Please see the present situation on my page.
[image]

Any suggestion will be useful.

Comment: What APIs do you have enabled from Google maps API?

Comment: Can you validate the list of APIs with list from my blog post -> https://tothecore.sk/2018/09/07/sitecore-sxa-set-google-maps-for-map-component-with-latest-pricing-changes/ ?

Comment: @PeterProcházka: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. We also did something like you. :) We enabled al the APIs using *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google changed their Maps API in June 2018 significantly and now you need to have API key generated with services enabled which was not needed before.

Steps to fix your issue:

1. Navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/new?project=project_name where `project_name` is name of your project
2. You should see something similar: [image]
3. Enabled all APIs, with "API" at the end of their name + Places API for Web by hitting "Enable" button: [image]
4. You should see something like this at the end: [image]
5. That's all you need to do

Check https://tothecore.sk/2018/09/07/sitecore-sxa-set-google-maps-for-map-component-with-latest-pricing-changes for further details